# Python injecting random number into tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, random, mocking

I have written code like this :

```
def choice(states):
    states = list(states)
    rnd = random.random()
    for state, p in states:
        rnd -= p
        if rnd <= 0:
            return state
```

And I need to  create some tests :

```
import unittest
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_choice(self):
        assertEquals(choice(states),something_equl)
```

How am I supposed to inject my own random number into test? to get deterministic results?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you could have `rnd` passed in but defaulting to `None`. Then in your function only generate `rnd` if it is `None`.

Comment: When you call your function you can do something like this random.randrange(0000,9999)

Comment: Have you considered using e.g. [`random.seed(0)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) to reset to a known state?

Comment: The description of the question should make clear that it is about *not* getting random data, but to get something deterministic... as it is, it's misleading (and I found it on the search for a simple way to get random data for tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) the `random.random()` function, example:

```
import random
import unittest
import mock


def choice(states):
    states = list(states)
    rnd = random.random()
    for state, p in states:
        rnd -= p
        if rnd <= 0:
            return state


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('random.random')
    def test_first_state_fires(self, random_call):
        random_call.return_value = 1
        self.assertEquals(choice([(1, 1)]), 1)

    @mock.patch('random.random')
    def test_returns_none(self, random_call):
        random_call.return_value = 2
        self.assertIsNone(choice([(1, 1)]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`unittest.mock` library](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to patch out the `random()` function. The library is part of Python 3.3 and up, you can install it separately as [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for older versions:

```
try:
    from unittest import mock
except ImportError:
    import mock

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('random.random')
    def test_choice(self, mock_random):
        mock_random.return_value = 0.42
        assertEquals(choice(states),something_equl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve the response with a full script to better understand and be adaptable to other cases.

```
import random
from unittest import TestCase, mock


def get_random_words(): # Simple function using choice
  l = []
  for _ in range(3):
      l.append(random.random(0, 10))
    
  return "".join([str(n) for n in l])

class TestRandom(TestCase):

   @mock.patch('random.random') # *(1)
   def test_get_random_words(self, mock_random):
    
      mock_random.side_effect = [1,7,3,6] # *(2)
      result = get_random_words()
    
      self.assertEqual(result, '173', 'Does not generate correct numbers')
```

## Considerations

*(1) For this example, the function is inside the same file, but in case it is in another file you must change the path of the patch
Ex: `@mock.patch('your_package.your_file.your_function.random.random')`

*(2) For this case, the `get_random_words` function calls `random.random` 3 times. This is why you must put equal or more items inside `mock_random.side_effect`. This is because if it has fewer items it will throw the `StopIteration` error.